# How to control a proportional valve with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, current, control, solenoid-valve

I would like to know how to control a proportional valve ([pvq13-5l-03-m5-a](https://www.smcpneumatics.com/pdfs/PVQ.pdf)) with an Arduino.

The valve operates with a constant 12 V and is driven by a current in the range of 0-170 mA.

Could you help me with components and circuit diagram?

I have tried to PWM a MOSFET (IRF520N) with the output of the MOSFET connected to the valve. I also had 12 V coming straight from a power supply, however, I didn't get it to work.

Comment: Show the circuit you used (all the circuit).

Comment: @Spehro    Thanks mate, will give it a go and let you know how it goes. One question you know on V2 Square, would that be the PWM pin on the board. Also, how would you control the current. I am assuming that it would vary depending on the duty cycle of the PWM signal.

Comment: I've converted this to a comment.  Spehro's answer explains how to obtain current control. Read it for understanding of how it works. (A controlled variable voltage across an R results in cmtrolled I as I = V/R)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use the circuit in my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511852/how-can-i-get-a-fixed-collector-current-from-s8050/511856?noredirect=1#comment1314793_511856) it will work for you.

Replace R1 with 2.7 ohms and replace the S8050 with a TIP122 with a small heatsink.

Of course the 3.7V becomes 12V and the 68 ohms represents your valve. Put a diode across the valve, such as 1N4148.